# Как найти произведение всех чисел в векторе?

Tags: c++

Подскажите, есть ли такая функция для вектора целых чисел?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Да, почти. Есть функция, которая умеет сворачивать (fold). Ей нужно передать два дополнительных параметра - начальное значение (в случае умножения это 1, это логично) и что делать с элементами (умножать). Вот код

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <functional>   // std::multiplies
#include <numeric>      // std::accumulate
#include <vector>

int main () {
  int init = 1;
  std::vector<int> numbers = {10,20,30};

  std::cout << std::accumulate(
                   numbers.begin(), // начало для умножения
                   numbers.end(),// конец для умножения
                   init,// начальное значение
                   std::multiplies<int>());// готовая функция умножения.
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, @KoVadim, вы прям волшебник.
____
Странное дело, у меня функция accumulate не в std пространстве. ) Ох уж эти стандарты.

Comment: Видимо, у Вас плохой компилятор. Случайно не в tr1 namespace?

Comment: Она в глобальном пространстве. А компилятор стандартный microsoft из mvs 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Или другой вариант:

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int Multi(vector<int> v) {
    int mul = 1;                     // сначала задаём множитель
    for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) { // v.size() возвращает количество элементов в векторе
        mul=mul*v[i];                // умножается mul на первый элемент вектора
    }                                // а т.к. mul=1, то переменная mul 
                                     //становится равна первому элементу вектора
    return mul;
}
int main() {
    vector<int> vec = { 10,20,30 };
    int res = Multi(vec);
    cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```